# Need help with ways to make money in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried looking for similar questions to this one but was unable to find any.  I'm wondering if theres someone that knows how to make real money in Skyrim.  I don't have dawnguard or hearthfire.  My blacksmithing is around 80, maybe 82ish, and ive tried mining kolskeggr mine and selling the gold ore to pavo but that seems really slow due to the respawn rate of the mine.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The suggestions in that thread look to be a few years old.  I had read that with some of the newer patches and updates, some of those methods don't work as well anymore.  The main one is the iron daggers.  It's said to not be as effective as it once was.  Can this be confirmed?

Comment: The iron dagger method I believe was actually focused for EXP, but either way they've patched the game to fix it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like the answers on the previous question need to be updated, then.  Here at Arqade, we don't allow questions that ask the same thing, regardless of how old they are.  This ensures that we don't have several questions all asking the same thing, and all of them saying something different.  One question, all the different ways to make money.

Comment: Understandable.  I didn't know it was under that topic so I thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have high speech skill as well as smithing a lot money can be made by using the "Transmute" spell to turn all your iron ore and silver ore into gold ore.  Then smith that into jewellery (if you have gems I'd use them) and sell those to Belethor or other traders.  You will need to have some of the speech skill perks and a reasonable level or you will lose money, not gain it.

Make sure you don't smelt the iron before using transmute because the spell only works on ore.

You could also spend time killing strong enemies (Dragons mostly) or doing thieves guild/Dark Brotherhood quests because they are very profitable.

Lastly, if you are willing to glitch a little there is a Whiterun glitch (works on all platforms). [Which is shown here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgj4qkzgtLQ)  There is an alternate way of getting out of Whiterun by hopping on a barrel along the wall near the Warmaidens, but this method should work.

Comment: is it a better idea to jump from town to town buying the iron ore instead of looking around mining it?  I usually don't find to much while mining.

Comment: I usually find a certain amount and simply buy whatever the Warmaiden has on hand when I start making the jewellery.  I imagine that you could probably make a lot of money hopping around town to town if you have good enough speech to make a profit so you should try it.  I would reccomend you grab a pick and head over to some iron mines, there's a list [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mines).  Simply because shops only refresh every second day.